# div button accessibility clickable

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader, wcag2.0

I have a div element (which has another div inside it) which currently has role="button".
This element is under the body, and this creates a violation when 
auditing with certain accessibility assessment tools (DAP specifically).

**The reason for the violation**: "All content must reside within a WAI-ARIA landmark or labelled region role"

**When using roles other than "button" it becomes unclickable when using the JAWS screen-reader.**

I've tried giving a role="complementary" the main div, and role="button" to its child div - this made the entire element unclickable using the keyboard.

Any suggestion will be most appreciated..
Thanks!

Comment: Could you post your code or a link to a test page please ?

Comment: @QuentinC <div id="ID1" class="Class1" role="button">
<div class="Class2">Click Here</div>
</div>. This is the code that creates the above violation. When trying to change the role of the main Div the element becomes unclickable.

Comment: Also, using HTML tags other than div is not an option..

Comment: When saying "the element becomes unclickable" - this is only true when using the keyboard (mouse click still works), and using NVDA.

Comment: OK. Try tabindex=0. 
But: "Also, using HTML tags other than div is not an option..." – => why ? You can do what you want with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The div where you are using the role as complimentary should have a tabindex of -1. The button you want to focus to should have a tabindex of 0/1. This will make sure that the accessibility readers will focus on this component and when they do, it will select the button.

Here is a link that may help:
https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/

Hope this helps!